# What is difference between "on a diet" and "in a diet"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is difference between "on a diet" and "in a diet"?

I know that "on a diet" is correct expression.

But, I want to know the cause that "in a diet" is not correct.

And I wonder why "in a hurry" is correct and "on a hurry" is not correct.

Both "on" and "in" have as meaning of state, don't they?

Comment: Some prepositional phrases are simply idiomatic. _On a diet_ and _in a hurry_ are great examples. Others would include: _on the phone, on hold, on a mission, on fire, in a pinch,_ and _in cold blood_.

Answer (score 2):

No doubt, some dictionaries say that you can use these prepositions to refer to a state, but they also say that you use the preposition "on" to refer to something that you are using, eating, or drinking. So you use "on", **not** "in", for examples:

1. I am on a diet.
2. He is on antibiotics.
3. He is on drugs.
4. He is on the phone.